# Return a value of type Self in a trait

Tags: rust

I am trying to write code as below, where I describe some code interface in a trait, and provide a default implementation (a mock in this case):

```rust
pub trait Person {
    fn say_hello(&self) -> String;
    
    fn stub() -> impl Person { // Doesn't work
        MockPerson {}
    }
}

pub struct MockPerson {}

impl Person for MockPerson {
    fn say_hello(&self) -> String {
        "hello".to_string()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find the right way to express that the trait `Person` has a static method to return some implementing type that is purposefully unknown:

```
pub trait Person {
    ...
    // `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types,
    // not in trait method return
    fn stub() -> impl Person { ... }
}
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Return position `impl Trait` is not supported in traits yet. See this [pre-RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/impl-trait-initiative/RFCs/rpit-in-traits.html). Why not just set the return type to `MockPerson`?

Comment: How do you plan to call this trait method? It doesn't take `self` so it can't be called via dynamic dispatch. This might be an unnecessary application of OOP to Rust.

Comment: > This might be an unnecessary application of OOP to Rust.
That's quite possible, I'm new to Rust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this code were allowed, it wouldn't be what you want, because:

1. You would have to mention some arbitrary concrete implementing type to *call* `Person::stub()`. Every associated item of a trait depends on the implementing type.
2. That type would be allowed to implement `stub()` to do something different.

The solution is to simply write a function that is not part of the trait. In Rust, it is entirely normal to have a *module* that contains items for a specific concept — rather than trying to fit everything into associated items of one trait or type.

```rust
mod person {
    pub trait Person {
        fn say_hello(&self) -> String;
    }

    pub fn stub() -> impl Person {
        MockPerson {}
    }
}
```

A real example in `std`: [`std::iter::empty()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.empty.html) is a function in the `std::iter` module, not in the `std::iter::Iterator` trait.

Comment: > In Rust, it is entirely normal to have a module that contains items for a specific concept
Thanks, that's a very useful perspective